# Same Height columns (multiple) of same height

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create HTML layout with foundation. My code is as below:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>

      <div class="medium-3 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
      <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>
<h2>Locations</h2>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="medium-9 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
 <div class="callout" data-equalizer-watch>

     <div class="row  relationship-model">
     <div class="medium-12 columns" >
     <div class="callout">
     <h2>Categories</h2>
      </div>
     </div>
          </div>
 <div class="row  relationship-model">
      <div class="medium-12 columns">
       <div class="callout">
     <h2>Location Current Request</h2>
     </div>
      </div>
            </div>


 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

output of above HTML as below:
[image]

While I want it as below:
[image]

I want left or right side columns to be of same height. I can do it with table but need same height and responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  color: red;
}
.left,
.box {
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 4;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">Lorem</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box">Lorem</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer="foo">

  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <div class="callout panel" data-equalizer-watch="foo">
      <h2>Locations</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <div class="panel" data-equalizer-watch="foo">
      <div class="row" data-equalizer="bar">
        <div class="callout panel" data-equalizer-watch="bar">
          <h2>Categories</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="callout panel" data-equalizer-watch="bar" style="margin-bottom:0">
          <h2>Location Current Request</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` is one of the best option. Please be aware of browser compatibility especially about android `flex` only support from **Andriod Browser 4.3**

Reference http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  color: red;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left box">Lorem</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box">Lorem</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Updated Answer

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  color: red;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
  align-self: baseline;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box">Lorem</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/dXSG8m6NrJGCYjJDf9ne?p=preview

Comment: if right side columns stretches then Left row automatically stretches but if left row stretches then right side columns does. It mean I need to make sure right side columns always bigger than left side. Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: @user2739418 You are looking for solution to avoid left box stretch ?

Comment: @user2739418 Please have a look the updated answer. Hope you are happy with it.